# Appropriate time gap for contacting a professor after an interview

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, canada

I had an interview for a research-based master's program in Canada over a month ago. Since the interview, I have not received any updates from the professor. What would be an appropriate time to wait before reaching out?

Is it possible that only accepted students are contacted, and others are not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month is long enough. Contact them and ask for any status update. It is possible, though a bit unlikely that only accepted people are contacted. Most institutions are polite enough to let people know one way or another. It is actually more efficient for them to send out non-acceptance notices so that they don't have to deal with individual queries.

But it is also possible that something was missed and an error was made. Contacting them can clear it up.

Your mail can also ask if there is any additional steps you should take or any additional materials they require from you.